# Eclipse don't run

Tags: java, eclipse

Hello I tried to install eclipse, but I doing something wrong, a few moments ago I install eclipse via terminal. Just hit apt install eclipse. I have JDK 9 and JRE 9. Eclipse give me a error log.

This is my error log

```
eclipse.buildId=debbuild
java.version=9.0.1
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_GB
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator 4 0 2018-03-02 16:41:15.343
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle "org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.0.301.dist [1]" could not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint: Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: CDC-1.1/Foundation-1.1,J2SE-1.4
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolverError(AbstractBundle.java:1332)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolutionFailureException(AbstractBundle.java:1316)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:323)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-03-02 16:41:15.351
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.0.301.dist.jar was not resolved.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2018-03-02 16:41:15.360
!MESSAGE One or more bundles are not resolved because the following root constraints are not resolved:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2018-03-02 16:41:15.360
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.0.301.dist.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator 2 0 2018-03-02 16:41:15.360
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.1))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.4)))".

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2018-03-02 16:41:15.362
!MESSAGE The following is a complete list of bundles which are not resolved, see the prior log entry for the root cause if it exists:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2018-03-02 16:41:15.362
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.0.301.dist [1] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator 2 0 2018-03-02 16:41:15.362
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.1))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.4)))".

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-03-02 16:41:15.363
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

What happened?

Comment: 1. Which OS distribution? What hardware platform? 2. Are you able to install and run eclipse manually (from [their site](https://www.eclipse.org)?

Comment: Early hunch:  Eclipse isn't quite compatible with JDK 9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version of Eclipse you are trying to use (probaby 3.8 or 4.2 judging by the plugin ids) is very old and doesn't understand Java 9. The layout of the Java 9 JRE/JDK directories has changed significantly and this is confusing this old Eclipse.

Use Eclipse Oxygen.2 4.7.2 to run with Java 9 or use Java 8 to run the old version of Eclipse.